# Azure b2c concurrent user logins

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to detect if a user is having concurrent logins to the same application over multiple browers/devices using Azure Active Directory B2C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Using B2C this is not currently supported, but there is an open feedback request out for this, which you can upvote.

you’d need your own session tracker which you might use via a rest api.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10686759-limit-conccurent-multiple-logins-in-b2c-ad

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. Will give it an upvote cheers.